# Are there downloadable documents for ".NET Framework Class Library"?

Tags: c#, documentation, standard-library

I often have to look up the information at ".NET Framework Class Library" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx

Microsoft website provides C# language specification in .doc word format. I wonder if we have some way to download ".NET Framework Class Library"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use an application called Zeal to download the the .NET Framework documentation. The documentation can then be viewed offline in Zeal. Not exactly a word document but better than nothing.

https://zealdocs.org/

If that doesn't work for you, I also found that Visual Studio can save those docs offline as well.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pakistan/2013/02/04/download-all-msdn-documentations-for-offline-access/

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx? Both seem to be about .NET Framework Class Library.

Comment: I'm really not sure what the difference there is. Without comparing it in detail, it looks about the same. Maybe out of order?

Comment: If you think that I have helped you out, then feel free to mark this as correct.